# next-images breaking all the absolute paths in my next.js project

Tags: next.js, next-images

I want to have inline png images on my next.js project. As this is not a native supported feature, I'm using the `next-images` library for that.

This is my `next.config.js`

```js
const withImages = require('next-images')
module.exports = withImages()
```

The problem is NOT the image import, but all the rest of imports: that code is breaking all the absolute `.jsx` imports on my project.

Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: How are you configuring the absolute paths in Next.js?

Comment: @juliomalves I don't have any configuration for that, I just import the .jsx files with `import SomeComponent from "/components/SomeComponent"`. And they worked until I installed next-images

Comment: I'd recommend a read through [Absolute Imports and Module path aliases](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/module-path-aliases).

Comment: @juliomalves the link you've just sent me has the answer to my question. Now it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the user @juliomalves mentioned above, the answer is [on this link](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/module-path-aliases) from the Next.js official documentation.

Basically, the issue was fixed in 2 steps:

1. Adding a `jsconfig.json` file (if you're using Typescript, you should use `tsconfig.json` instead).
2. changing all the absolute paths from `/components/Something` to `components/Something` (in other words, removing the first forward slash).

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior of `next/image` will add `/_next/image?url=` to any absolute URL of image `src`.

A workaround is use `imgix loader` and set path to `''`:

```js
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  images: {
    domains: ['yourServer.com'],
    path: '',
    loader: 'imgix',
  },
}
```

---

From source code, add `root = '/_next/image?url=...'` to any absolute URL `src` is by design:
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/f81a6a5f0fc3a33a51112d4d3261d431e704b0da/packages/next/client/image.tsx#L862

Why?

It's a little strange, different from the HTML `<image src="">` behavior, makes users confused too.

You can follow https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/19206 for follow-up

Comment: OP isn't using the `next/image` component. The question is about the [`next-images`](https://github.com/twopluszero/next-images) plugin for Next.js.